# Read attribute value from XML which contains prefix with colon in element name and attribute name

Tags: php, xml, xpath

I have element in XML like below

```
<user:name test:one = "firstUser" />
```

I use **PHP DOM Xpath** to read XML

$doc = new DOMDocument();

```
$xpath = new DOMXPath($doc);
$xml = simplexml_load_file(file path here);
echo '<pre>'; print_r($xml);
```

and output is blank

```
SimpleXMLElement Object
(
)
```

If I try removing **:** and prefix like below

```
<name one = "firstUser" />
```

then it reads element. output is

```
SimpleXMLElement Object
(
    [name] => SimpleXMLElement Object
    (
        [@attributes] => Array
        (
            [one] => firstUser
        )
    )
)
```

How I can read element value with **prefix and colon (:)**

Updated : sample XML file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<root xmlns:test="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"  xmlns:user="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
    <user:name test:one = "firstUser" />
    <name second = "secondUser" />
</root>
```

Comment: add `user` as namespaces in http://php.net/manual/en/function.simplexml-load-file.php, maybe `test` too

Comment: Still same issue

Comment: what php version do you use? check this: https://3v4l.org/ijeHp it works, but has some warnings

Comment: PHP Version 5.6.19

Comment: It works but if I use external XML file same issue

Comment: I updated sample XML file in question

Comment: It shows secondUser but not firstUser which is with colon

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `DOMDocument` to go through the document:

```
<?php
$doc = new DOMDocument();
$doc->load("file.xml");
$root = $doc->getElementsByTagName("root");
echo "<pre>";
foreach ($doc->getElementsByTagName("name") as $users) {
    echo $users->nodeName.":";
    foreach ($users->attributes as $attr) {
        echo $attr->name." ".$attr->value."<br>";
    }
    echo "<br>";
}
```

[Demo (XML loaded from string)](https://3v4l.org/ZfUR3)